# I keep getting a 500 internal server error after 60 seconds with PHP script

Tags: php, apache, internal-server-error, php-ini

Firstly I have PHP errors switched on but I keep getting this 500 error when I run this script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
$location = '/dir/';

mkdir($location.date('Y-m-d'), 0700);

$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));

function createZipFromDir($dir, $zip_file) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if (true !== $zip->open($zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {
        return false;
    }
    zipDir($dir, $zip);
    return $zip;
}

function zipDir($dir, $zip, $relative_path = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
    $dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        $i=0;
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) || $i < 5) {
            if (file === '.' || $file === '..') {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_file($dir . $file)) {
                $zip->addFile($dir . $file, $file);
            } elseif (is_dir($dir . $file)) {
                zipDir($dir . $file, $zip, $relative_path . $file);
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

createZipFromDir($location.$yesterday, 'files.zip');

?>
```

The script basically archives a folder each day into a ZIP file. I can confirm that script works fine when I test it with small files. But this time it is trying to archive data which is a few hundred mb.

My max_execution_time is set to 18000 in my php.ini file, and this is correct as it shows up in my phpinfo() file.

Does anyone know why I am getting a 500 internal error?

Peter

Comment: You or your hoster has installed PHP as CGI-Wrapper. And that is the problem. You cant handle the execution time if the webserver kills the process automatically.

Comment: How do you know for certain, is there any way around this?

Comment: Try to increase the memory size.

Comment: I have executed script longer than this before with the same host

Comment: My memory size is at 12000M, that didn't help increasing it

Comment: I see a stray `$root` variable. Is it used elsewhere? It's not posted in your code. Maybe it needs to be another name; `rtrim($dir.$zip...` for instance(?) Hard to say. Since it's inside `zipDir($dir, $zip, $relative_path` the `$dir` I mean.

Comment: Sorry, root was meant to be deleted. I dleted it but still get the error

Comment: I also noticed you commented out a line of your code near the beginning, where this variable `$yesterday` is being used at the end. Other than that, I can't say for certain.

Comment: $yerserday is defined. I didn't include it in that code, but it is a date.

Comment: Then, you will need to show your actual production code in order for others to help; they stand at asking some of the same questions as I did. I can't be of any further help, sorry.

Comment: Updated code just now

Comment: Ok, but you haven't gotten rid of `$root`

Comment: [this guy](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#112044) seems to have worked through these issues. Maybe something there can help.